# Extract YYYYMMDD from [Char] and create DateTime value

Tags: haskell

I have String containing Dates with the following format "YYYYMMDD". This is for granted, no possibility of errors.

I want to create DateTime from them.

I manage to have something working , but it seems very complicated to such small things:

```
-- Only works in base 10 , for positive values
stringToInt :: String -> Int
stringToInt [] = 0
stringToInt (x:xs) = (digitToInt x * 10^length xs ) + (stringToInt xs) 

-- Expecting format = "YYYYMMDD"
stringToDateTime :: String -> DateTime
stringToDateTime s = DateTime year month day 0 0 0
  where year = stringToInt $ take 4 s 
        month = stringToInt $ take(6-4) . drop 4 $ s
        day = stringToInt $ take(8-6) . drop 6 $ s

date1 = stringToDateTime "20180409"
```

I tried the parseDate function , but could not managed to have it working, as I could not found what it the expected String format (here is [Data.Dates doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dates-0.2.2.1/docs/Data-Dates.html) : how can we know the expected format ?)

That is why I end up doing myself function for creating a DateTime from my String, and doing so I had to create a function for converting an Int from a [Char] , because  I could not find an already existing function for this.

Comment: Will this help you `let [y1,y2,y3,y4,m1,m2,d1,d2] = "20180409" in (read [y1,y2,y3,y4] :: Int, read [m1,m2] :: Int, read [d1,d2] :: Int)`?

Comment: I'd say you need https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strptime-1.0.10/docs/Data-Time-Parse.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `dates` package, I think you need `parseDateFormat`:

```
> import Data.Dates
> import Data.Dates.Formats (parseDateFormat)
> parseDateFormat "YYYYMMDD" "20180409"
Right 9 April 2018, 0:0:0
```

If you're sure that your string has the correct date format, you can extract the result from `Right` with `fromRight'` of the `extra` package:

```
> import Data.Either.Extra
> fromRight' $ parseDateFormat "YYYYMMDD" "20180409"
9 April 2018, 0:0:0
```

Answer (score 2):

For doing such stuff “properly”, you should read up on parser combinator libraries. A (very much overkill) solution using the [megaparsec library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec):

```
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Control.Monad

type Parser = Parsec String String

decimalNInt :: Int -> Parser Int
decimalNInt nDigits = read <$> replicateM nDigits digitChar

data DateTime = DateTime Int Int Int Int Int Int deriving (Show)

dateYYYYMMDD :: Parser DateTime
dateYYYYMMDD = DateTime <$>
       decimalNInt 4 <*> decimalNInt 2 <*> decimalNInt 2
   <*> pure 0 <*> pure 0 <*> pure 0
```

```
> runParser dateYYYYMMDD "" "20180409"
    Right (DateTime 2018 4 9 0 0 0)
> runParser dateYYYYMMDD "" "2018009"
    Left (TrivialError (SourcePos {sourceName = "", sourceLine = Pos 1, sourceColumn = Pos 8} :| []) (Just EndOfInput) (fromList [Label ('d' :| "igit")]))
> runParser dateYYYYMMDD "" "abcdefgh"
    Left (TrivialError (SourcePos {sourceName = "", sourceLine = Pos 1, sourceColumn = Pos 1} :| []) (Just (Tokens ('a' :| ""))) (fromList [Label ('d' :| "igit")]))
```

In perhaps better understandable monadic notation, the parser would look thus:

```
dateYYYYMMDD = do
    year <- decimalNInt 4
    month <- decimalNInt 2
    day <- decimalNInt 2
    return $ DateTime year month day 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The slicing I think you have to do yourself, but to read a Integer from a string you should use the function [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read), like so:

```
read "1234" :: Int
```

For this function to work on any data type, it must be an instance of the class [`Read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Read). Unfortunately, looking at the documentation, DateTime is not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parseTimeM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:parseTimeM), from the only Haskell package that really treats dates and times carefully, [time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time). It is a quite comprehensive library; the only thing it really lacks is natural-language processing and production.

```
Data.Time> parseTimeM False defaultTimeLocale "%0Y%m%d" "20180409" :: Maybe Day
Just 2018-04-09
```

The documentation linked above and the documentation for [`formatTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:formatTime) give a complete list of available format specifiers.

If you really need `DateTime` and no substitute will do, you can extract the year, month, and day from a `Day` with [`toGregorian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.1/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:toGregorian).

Comment: You beat me to it, and amusingly, my example date would have been "20180309". :-D

Comment: “Only Haskell package that treats dates and times carefully” – on what basis do you make that statement? I find `time` a bit, if you permit the pun, _dated_. [`thyme`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thyme) seems the natural successor, which improves upon it both in terms of API and performance.